# Is it possible to construct a ring morphism $A \times A \to B$ from a ring morphism $A \to B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $A$ and $B$ be two rings and $\varphi : A \to B$ a ring morphism.

We equip $A \times A$ with the induced ring structure from $A$.

I was wondering if it is possible to construct a ring morphism $\tilde{\varphi} : A \times A \to B$ from $\varphi$ different from the composition with the natural projections (i.e. different from $(x, y) \mapsto \varphi(x)$ and $(x,y) \mapsto \varphi(y)$) ?

Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

K. Y.

Comment: Not in general, e.g. take $A = B$ to be a field with no nontrivial endomorphisms such as a prime field and take $\varphi$ to be the identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be constructed if $B$ isn't [directly reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_ring). Then there exists a non-trivial [central idempotent element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_(ring_theory)) in $B$.

Suppose $\overline\phi(1,0)=a,\overline \phi(0,1)=b$, then we have $ab=0$, $a+b=1$. So $a(1-a)=0$ or $a^2=a$, so existence of idempotent element is a necessary condition.

It's sufficient if we also requires $a$ to be in the center, then we can take $\overline \phi:(m,n)\mapsto a\cdot \phi(m)+b\cdot\phi(n)$.

Addition:
\begin{align}
\overline\phi((m_1,n_1))+\overline \phi((m_2,n_2))&=a\cdot\phi(m_1)+b\cdot\phi(n_1)+a\cdot\phi(m_2)+b\cdot\phi(n_2)\\
&=a\cdot\phi(m_1+m_2)+b\cdot\phi(n_1+n_2)\\
&=\overline\phi((m_1+m_2,n_1+n_2))
\end{align}

Multiplication, we need
$$b^2=(1-a)^2=1-2a+a^2=1-a=b$$
Then:
\begin{align}
\overline\phi((m_1,n_1))\cdot\overline\phi((m_2,n_2))&=(a\cdot\phi(m_1)+b\cdot\phi(n_1))(a\cdot \phi(m_2)+b\cdot\phi(n_2))\\
&=a^2\cdot\phi(m_1m_2)+b^2\cdot\phi(n_1n_2)\\
&=a\cdot\phi(m_1m_2)+b\cdot\phi(n_1n_2)\\
&=\overline\phi((m_1m_2,n_1n_2))
\end{align}

In this construction, we only used that $a$ commutes with $\mathrm{im}\, \phi $, which I'm not sure is it a necessary condition.

One example that can be constructed is: $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, sending $(m,n)\mapsto 3m-2n$.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that you're also supposing $B$ to be commutative, right ?

Comment: @YADDADEN I didn't, that's why I went to show that $ba=0$ and stuff.

Comment: Then how did you do to pass from $a \phi(m_1) \cdot a \phi(m_2)$ to $a^2 \phi(m_1m_2)$ ?

Comment: @YADDADEN I see now, will update the answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Or, maybe it is possible for $a$ and $b$ to be central elements and satisfy $ab=0$ and $a+b=1$ ?